# java: loop produces incorrect output when reading from file?

Tags: java, file, while-loop, average, scanning

This loop is producing the average values of hours and amount paid, but the output is mathematically incorrect. How can I edit this code to produce the correct average hours value and average paid values?

```
         Scanner openFile = new Scanner(inFile);
         while (openFile.hasNext()) {
                if (openFile.hasNextDouble()) {
                    totalHours += openFile.nextDouble();
                    numOfHourInputs++;
                }
                if (openFile.hasNextDouble()) {
                    totalPaid += openFile.nextDouble();
                    numOfCharges++;
                }
                else {
                    openFile.next(); }
            }

        averageHours = (totalHours/numOfHourInputs);
        averagePaid = (totalPaid/numOfCharges);
```

Below is my file:
The first column is unimportant for calculating the averages. The second column contains the numbers of hours. The third column contains the charges.

This file can have more data added to it by the user - the values inside of the file can be changed.

`a 10.0 9.95
b 10.0 13.95
b 20.0 13.95
c 50.0 19.95
c 30.0 19.95`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the else:

```
else {
    openFile.next(); //this consumes all input
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code

```
Double[][] values = {{10.0, 9.95},
        {10.0, 13.95},
        {20.0, 13.95},
        {50.0, 19.95},
        {30.0, 19.95}};

Double totalHours = 0.;
int numOfHourInputs = 0;
Double totalPaid = 0.;
int numOfCharges = 0;

for (final Double[] value : values) {
    totalHours += value[0];
    numOfHourInputs++;

    totalPaid += value[1];
    numOfCharges++;
}

final double averageHours = (totalHours / numOfHourInputs);
System.out.println("averageHours = " + averageHours);

final double averagePaid = (totalPaid / numOfCharges);
System.out.println("averagePaid = " + averagePaid);
```

produced the result

```
averageHours = 24.0
averagePaid = 15.55
```

so that it's clearly not a mathematical problem. Check your input code especially for the line

```
openFile.next();
```

Comment: what if the user could add more data to the file? so  `Double[ ] [ ] values` could change? how would I read in more values from the file if it changed? @smutje

Comment: Please consult the internet on how to read a file into an arbitrary data structure of your liking - an array of double for example. There are a zillion examples for this kind of problem!

Answer (score 1):

You still need to skip the first token but in the right spot:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double totalHours = 0.0;
    int numOfHourInputs = 0;

    double totalPaid = 0.0;
    int numOfCharges = 0;

    Scanner openFile = null;

    try
    {
        openFile = new Scanner(new File("c:\\temp\\pay.txt"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("FNF");
    }

    try
    {
        while (openFile.hasNext()) 
        {
            // skip the first token
            String token = openFile.next();

            if (openFile.hasNextDouble()) 
            {
               totalHours += openFile.nextDouble();
               numOfHourInputs++;
            }
            if (openFile.hasNextDouble()) 
            {
               totalPaid += openFile.nextDouble();
               numOfCharges++;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        openFile.close();
    }

   double averageHours = (totalHours/numOfHourInputs);
   double averagePaid = (totalPaid/numOfCharges);

   System.out.println("Total hours: " + totalHours);
   System.out.println("Num hours input: " + numOfHourInputs);
   System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
   System.out.println("Average hours: " + averageHours);
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("Total payments: " + totalPaid);
   System.out.println("Num payments input: " + numOfCharges);
   System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
   System.out.println("Average paid: " + averagePaid);
}
```

Here is the output that I get:

```
Total hours: 120.0
Num hours input: 5
----------------------------------------
Average hours: 24.0

Total payments: 77.75
Num payments input: 5
----------------------------------------
Average paid: 15.55
```

Comment: What do you mean by skipping the first token? How could I execute that? @michael

Comment: The first token in your example was the a/b/c, so openFile.next() is just reading that in and moving to the next one without doing anything with the value.

Comment: How do I get the program to calculate the averages with all of the values in the file instead of it skipping over values? @michael

Comment: This isn't skipping over values, it is skipping the non-value field.  Your example had a line listed as "a 10.0 9.95" so the first openFile.next() statement is skipping "a".  if your line doesn't actually have "a" in it, take out the line that is calling openFile.next();

Comment: I've added the output above.